# Updating folder path in Windows 10 photo app?

Tags: windows-10, photos, sqlite, folder-redirection

After several weeks work putting together a holiday video using the Windows 10 Photo App when I now open the app it can no longer find any of my photos. Every file in the Storyboard shows the sad emoticon and a message stating "We can't find this file".

I have tried all of the obvious steps of updating Settings -> Sources to include the folder containing all the source material (`E:\Photos`)

Being understandably reluctant to give up completely on my work I discovered that the file format is SQLite and so managed to open the database using DB Browser for SQLite. The table Folder reveals the list below. I have tried various SQL scripts to try to correct the references to point to `E:\Photos`, all of which have failed.

When first opening the database to view the folders I also receive a message stating I have missing collating sequences. I've been told this is because the database is using collating sequences that are missing in DB Browser.

Can anyone please suggest how to correct the references in the database so that Windows 10 Photo App is able to find my photos?

```
sqlite> .width 5 50
sqlite> SELECT Folder_Id,Folder_Path FROM Folder;

1      C:\Users\carlo\Pictures                           
2      C:\Users\carlo\Pictures\Saved Pictures            
3      C:\Users\carlo\Pictures\Camera Roll               
4                                                        
5                                                        
6                                                        
7      C:\Users\carlo\Pictures\Exported videos           
13     C:\Users\carlo\Pictures\2018-09                   
14     C:\Users\carlo\Pictures\2018-08                   
16     C:\Users\carlo\Pictures\GoPro                     
17     C:\Users\carlo\OneDrive\Pictures                  
20                                                       
21                                                       
22                                                       
23     C:\Users\carlo\OneDrive\Pictures\Camera imports   
24     C:\Users\carlo\OneDrive\Pictures\Camera imports
25     E:\Photos
```

Answer (score 0):

If Photos is looking for your photos in folder `C:\Users\carlo\Pictures`,
while they are really in folder `E:\Photos`, you can in effect add
`E:\Photos` to `C:\Users\carlo\Pictures` via symbolic links (junctions).

Start a Command Prompt (cmd) and enter the following command:

```
mklink /J E:\Photos C:\Users\carlo\Pictures
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply and sorry for the delayed response. I did try running the above command in administrator mode which resulted in the response: "Cannot create a file when that file already exists." I'm not sure why, I also tried downloading the shell extension to try to do the same thing using explorer which shows the folder link being created but once again the Storyboard in the Photo App still can't find the file. If only there was a way to see what file the App is trying to find and where it's trying to read it from.

Comment: Use [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to trace a process.

Answer (score -1):

I uninstalled the Photos apps from the Microsoft store because I got the same error your reported. Process Monitor by Sysinternals was of no help, other than showing Windows Photos app repeatedly. After uninstalling it, the default image program became MS Paint which did not give the error. I'm going to chalk it up to medicore Microsoft software development once and use free alternatives when possible. I don't want to trash a company lightly, but after having used their operating system and applications for over 30 years, this is the conclusion I've reached after years of qualitative data gathering.